# Avoiding Concurrency exceptions in libgdx with server/client threads

Tags: java, multithreading, networking, libgdx

Basically, I have a LibGDX desktop application. I also have a server that the client connects to. The connection to the server runs on it's own personal thread with an ObjectInputStream.

Here's my issue: If an item is removed from say, the Item list on the ground by a packet received, I run the risk of getting a Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException because it's not run on the same thread.

The only option I know of is to make every packet received run on Gdx.app.postRunnable(). But I know creating all these threads could be a really bad idea.

Is there a way that I could link up the packet input thread and the LWJGL thread to avoid these issues without holding up the main opengl thread? Or is postRunnable() not as dangerous as I'm thinking?

Unfortunately these issue is a hard thing to google, I've attempted recuriting help from the LibGDX help IRC channel but was unable to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the libGDX `postRunnable()` is as heavy-weight as you fear.  First a `Runnable` is not a thread.  Its just an object with a `run` method.  So the cost is mostly just the memory cost of allocating the object.

In a Libgdx app, each time the libgdx render loop runs, [it fetches a list of `Runnable` objects that have been queued by `postRunnable`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/3fbd96a706be9019dde0cc5ac60122cd67c4b224/backends/gdx-backend-android/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidGraphics.java#L400) and executes the `run()` method on each one in turn.  It then processes any event handlers, and then invokes the app's render callback.

If you are careful to not allocate a new `Runnable` instance, "posting" a Runnable should be a relatively cheap operation (especially compared to receiving network traffic).

That said, you probably want to do as much processing of the packet as you can in isolation (e.g., to make sure its complete and well-formed) in the background thread, but as soon as you want to interact with objects that the main render thread is also interacting with, you are probably best off posting a `Runnable`.  The `run` callback should not block (as you'll block the render thread), but it should be safe to interact with OpenGL state from inside the callback.